# No public port '22/tcp' published for test_sshd

Tags: docker

I'm trying to execute this:

https://hub.docker.com/r/rastasheep/ubuntu-sshd/

Namely, I run:

```
sudo docker run -d -P --name test_sshd rastasheep/ubuntu-sshd:16.04
```

Then

```
sudo docker port test_sshd 22
```

I can see something like:

```
0.0.0.0:49154
```

And I can run:

```
ssh root@localhost -p 49154
```

But as soon as I restart my computer, I see this:

```
sudo docker port test_sshd 22
Error: No public port '22/tcp' published for test_sshd
```

Could you give me a kick here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option *-P* binds a port dynamically and randomly, that's why you need another step to associate a port, using `docker port`.
I would use instead a free static port to access ssh port to this container :

```
docker container run -d -p 2222:22 --name test_sshd rastasheep/ubuntu-sshd:16.04
ssh root@localhost -p 2222
```

This port setting persists when *dockerd* is restarted.